# Can you programmatically set a property in a ControlTemplate from a ChildWindow?

Tags: silverlight, binding

I am working on a Silverlight application that has resource files that define styles for the different types of Child Windows in the application. The `<Style>` contains `<ControlTemplate>` markup with various content. Is there a way to set one of the properties of the controls defined within the `<ControlTemplate>` from the Child Window's class?

For example, imagine in the resource file I have markup like the following:

```
<Style x:Key="MyChildWindowStyle" TargetType="sdk:ChildWindow">
  <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:ChildWindow">
           <Grid x:Name="Root">
              ...
              <Image Source="/Assets/image.png" />
              ...
           </Grid>
        </ContentTemplate>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now assume that I have a number of child windows that are configured to use this style. What I'd like to be able to do is from the code in those child windows be able to programmatically change the value of the image's `Source`.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried making image source a BitmapImage resource? (with a key lets say myImage). Then refer that from Image source with {DynamicResource myImage} and set that resource from your child controls

Comment: @zahir: No, I have not tried that. Do you have an article/blog about that technique that I can read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@zahir's answer pointed me in the right direction, but to get it to work in Silverlight I had to do the following:

First, I added the `<BitmapImage>` markup to my resource file, using the `UriSource` property to specify the default value.

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="MyImage" UriSource="../Assets/DefaultImage.png" />
```

Next, I referenced it in the `<ControlTemplate>` like so:

```
<Image ... Source="{StaticResource MyImage}"/>
```

Then, in my code-behind class I was able to modify the `UriSource` property like so:

```
BitmapImage img = (Application.Current.Resources["MyImage"] as BitmapImage);
if (img != null)
    img.UriSource = "../Assets/NewImage.png";
```

Of course, the precise values for `UriSource` would depend on how you are handling image assets, where they are located, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your resources  you can do this:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="MyImage" Source="/Assets/image.png"/>

<Style x:Key="MyChildWindowStyle" TargetType="sdk:ChildWindow">
    ...
    <Image Source="{DynamicResource MyImage}" />
    ...
</Style>
```

Then in your child window's code-behind you can do this:

```
Resources["MyImage"] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/other-image.png"));
```

But if your child window class is in another assembly you should be writing the uri a bit different:

```
Resources["MyImage"] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyOtherAssemblyShortName;component/Assets/other-image.png"));
```

You can check [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) for package uri format.

But I suggest you to use MVVM pattern in order to get most out of WPF in terms of bindings, styling etc. When you have a view model instead of a code-behind these things become simpler. You may wanna check the related [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), a [codeproject sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/278901/MVVM-Pattern-Made-Simple), [a toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) or [a validation mechanism](http://mvvmvalidation.codeplex.com/) designed for MVVM.

Comment: where do I put the <BitmapImage>? I put it at the top of my resource file (I had to use the property `UriSource`, not `Source`, btw), but when I do `Resources["MyImage"]` I get back `null`. Also, I am using Silverlight 5, not WPF.